# Making Value Comparison Between Textboxes

Tags: c#, textbox

There are several textboxes and the values each one of them increasing sequeantially. I mean

textbox1.Text<textbox2.Text<textbox3.Text<textbbox4.Text<.....

Which event can be used to validate this condtions. In the code below i used textChanged but in the scenario for example the value in the `textbox1.Text=30` afterward when istart to type to `textbox1.Text`  value 5 (which i inteded to enter 59) the focus jump to `textbox1`. What is the correct event comparing for two textboxes.

```
    private void textbox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (double.Parse(textbox1.Text) > double.Parse(textbox2.Text))
        {
            textbox1.Focus();
            errProvider1.SetError(textbox1, "Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: When do you need to compare them?  On submit, then move the code there and if they dont match return error and it will stop submitting.  If it is some other reason do on textbox leave event/loose focus (or whatever the name was) possibly.

Comment: You can use the `Leave`-event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Remove the **textbox1.Focus()**, but keep the visual part of the error (which i suppose are handled by the *errorprovider*.

It's ok to check the values while the user enters them, but **don't** interrupt the flow (that is move the focus)!

As Tim suggests, you can move the code to the *Leave* event, but this might not be fired if the user presses a button (or worse use a shortcut).